# Correct signature not found for ItemTapped event handler

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have the following XAML view, and when the Item is tapped I want to navigate to a detail page:

```
 <ListView x:Name="ProductsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}"
                  ItemTapped="ProductItem_OnTapped">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local1:ProductTemplate />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

This is the handler:

```
public async void ProductItem_OnTapped(ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var productDetailVM = new ProductDetailViewModel(SelectedProduct);
    var productDetailView = new ProductDetail();
    productDetailView.BindingContext = productDetailVM;

    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(productDetailView);
}
```

The error I am getting is this:

> EventHandler "ProductItem_OnTapped" with correct signature not found in type "ProductTest.MainPage".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ProductItem_OnTapped` should be declared with a first sender parameter of type object, also make sure it is defined in the code-behind (`MainPage.xaml.cs` in this case).

```
public async void ProductItem_OnTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
```